# How do I left align a div

Tags: html, css, css-float

I would like some help with left aligning the content on the site I am working on. I have a menu on the left hand side and I need a content div to site adjacent to this menu.

In my CSS I currently have the following AND The HTML Looks like this:

```css
    #pageContent_wrapper {
        width:100%;
        
    }
    #container {
        width:940px;
        height:100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .page-content {
        float:left;
        padding: 30px 0;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="pageContent_wrapper">
        <div id="container">
           <div class="page-content">
              <p>Content goes Here</p>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This doesn't work though. Essentially I am trying to left align a div with the main content in it.

Comment: What part of it all doesn't work?

Comment: You already have things aligning to the left. Your `#container` has a `width: 940px` and `margin: 0 auto;` (and so will have a margin on larger screens), is that what you mean by not 'left aligning'

Comment: The content is already left aligned. Check <a href="http://jsfiddle.net/tMFPS/">jsFiddle</a>

Comment: you have to apply "margin: 0 auto;" on ".page-content" not on "#container"

Comment: The content is already left aligned. Check <a href="http://jsfiddle.net/tMFPS/">jsFiddle</a>

Comment: The float left didnt work. I have sorted the left align issue by using the following in the CSS:                                               `.page-content { position: absolute; top:50px; left: 15%; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `margin: 0 auto;` from the `#container`.
You also don't need `float: left` in the `.page-content`.
Whole CSS should look like this:

```
#pageContent_wrapper {
    width:100%;
}
#container {
    width:940px;
    height:100%;
}

.page-content {
    padding: 30px 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @matewka I have changed my css and used absolute positioning instead. What I failed to mention in my question is that I have a fixed position menu on the left. I have left aligned the main content with the below CSS:                                                      `.page-content {
 
 position: absolute;
 top:50px;
 left: 15%;

}`

Comment: Adding `position: absolute` to the significant part of the website could be dangerous. I don't recommend it and many people would agree with me. Instead of that try to add `margin-left: ..px` to the `#container` (or to the `.page-content` - denpending on which level the menu is placed). In the dotted chunk put the actual width of the fixed menu.

Answer (score 1):

add in you css

```
 text-align:left
```

And remove

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

waiting for your replay....

Comment: The text is already left aligned I wanted to make it look like the actual content is left aligned but I have since added the code below:   `.page-content { position: absolute; top:50px; left: 15%; }` This sorted it out for me.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @matewka you are quite right adding position absolute to the container is not a good idea I have had a couple of people say the same thing. So instead what I have done is added a `float:left` to the container with `padding-left:270px` which works perfectly! Because it means no matter what the content within my container it will always sit that many pixels away from the menu on the left and the content is left aligned with the float.

I don't think I explained exactly what the problem was when I wrote my question. Thank you for your help though.